Search with multiple inputs (checkboxes)
For a new design I'm creating a search where people can generate a report for companies (see image). The parent companies can have a lot of child companies. It is based on the blazer component DropDown grouping with multiple selection link (https://blazor.radzen.com/dropdown-grouping). But the problem I have is I want to select the parent that automatically selects the child companies but I also want an option to only select the parent company so no child companies are selected. Does anybody have a solution regarding this matter?


You can have a small tertiary button of select all to select all the children in a parent and else when a check box is selected - only the selected option is choose.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
